# How can we use variable of the request which are inside if controller

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am facing issues like I have some requests inside if controller and from those requests, I am fetching some json data and I have to use that data in another if controller and outside from if controller, but I am not able to get that data.
please help me out.
My test plan structure is like this-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitations in passing the variables between If Controllers, once the variable is set up it will be visible for this thread (virtual user) until its termination. As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)  `Variables are local to a thread;` so if you define the variable in 1st If Controller (assuming that the logic will be executed) the variable will be visible for all the Samplers which are "below"

Demo:

[image]

So my expectation is that your "fetching some json data" process fails somewhere somehow, double check your Post-Processor configuration and ensure that the variable is there and has its respective value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)